# QR Code Generator in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, charts, qr-code

I am looking for help to implement a QR Code generator on my site. The site is built in Ruby on Rails. I have tried to use rqrcode but could not seem to get it to work. I would like to use the google chart API.

OVERVIEW:

A simple QR code generator. In the view, a user can pass in a string, the string is then stored, and then sent to the QR code generator script, at this point the resulting QR Code image should be displayed back to the user.

Comment: The amount of people on this website that care about your ALL CAPS URGENCY: 1

Answer (score 13):

Just released a gem that makes this very easy if you're using rails 3.

Follow the installation documentation at:
https://github.com/samvincent/rqrcode-rails3

Comment: Does what it says on the tin.

Answer (score 12):

See: http://code.google.com/apis/chart/infographics/docs/qr_codes.html.

> QR codes are a popular type of two-dimensional barcode. They are also known as *hardlinks* or *physical world hyperlinks*. QR Codes store up to 4,296 alphanumeric characters of arbitrary text. This text can be anything, for example URL, contact information, a telephone number, even a poem! QR codes can be read by an optical device with the appropriate software. Such devices range from dedicated QR code readers to mobile phones...

Comment: Important: The Infographics portion of Google Chart Tools has been officially deprecated as of April 20, 2012. It will continue to work as per our deprecation policy

Answer (score 1):

I've both used google and the gem.

define @url in controller.  Use google API.

```
 <img src=<%="https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=545x545&cht=qr&chl=#{@url}&choe=UTF-8"%> alt="QR code">
```

If for some reason you want to have a gem do it on your server the following is good.

```
gem 'rqrcode'

@qr = RQRCode::QRCode.new( @url, :size => 7, :level => :h )

## Your VIEW
<div id="qr">

<style type="text/css">
#qr table {
  border-width: 0;
  border-style: none;
  border-color: #0000ff;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

#qr td {
  border-left: solid 10px #000;
  padding: 0; 
  margin: 0; 
  width: 0px; 
  height: 10px; 
}

#qr td.black { border-color: #000; }
#qr td.white { border-color: #fff; }
</style>

<%= raw @qr.as_html %>
</div>
```

Comment: Google API looks much easier.